# How can I get a secure system-wide oh-my-zsh configuration?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'd like to have a system-wide oh-my-zsh setup, but I'm not sure what would be the "best" approach for this. It is not my intention to ask about personal preferences or the like, I'm just unsure whether the solutions below are:

- `ln` my local user configuration somewhere doesn't seem right, because adding an exploit to my local cfg and therefore gain root permissions would be very easy.
- Installing oh-my-zsh to `/etc` would be maybe also a security hole because I simply haven't written it by myself.
- Simply writing my own personal `.zshrc` would be the last approach I would like to try out because it’s very time-consuming.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Putting it in `/etc` is no more insecure than if you install it in your home directory and allow other users to use it. This is really a question for superuser.com or perhaps serverfault.com, though.

Comment: @chepner the point of my concern was that with /etc, the cfg would be executed for every user, i.e. also for root, which is in my understanding a potential security hole. But it seems, that every solution, which refers to a user cfg has that problem. But thanks for the hint to ask on superuser.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Fair Warning: this assumes a Debian style linux, but this should work on other forms as well. This also assumes you are starting from scratch.*

**Part 1**, the install:

You will need to install zsh system wide, and not just for one user. (you may have already done this but I'll include it just to be comprehensive)

make sure you have installed zsh, simply: `sudo apt-get install zsh`

Follow the [oh-my-zsh install](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) guide or you can either:

use curl

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

use wget

```
sh -c "$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"
```

**Part 2**, Setting up zsh when new users are added:

You will need to make it so that new users default to zsh. In your `/etc/adduser.conf` file edit the line that says:

```
DSHELL=/bin/sh
```

to:

```
DSHELL=/bin/zsh
```

You should also change it for the `/etc/default/useradd` file, change the line:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
```

to:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh
```

**Part 3**, set your custom theme.

I have a custom theme file ([here](https://github.com/SpaceySciences/moci-zsh-theme)) that I wanted all users on the system to have. First, you should add the file to your `.oh-my-zsh/themes` folder:

```
cp your_custom_style.zsh-theme ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes
```

Next, edit your `.zshrc` file in your home directory, change the `ZSH_THEME="default"` to `ZSH_THEME="your_custom_style"`

Then, reload your `.zshrc` file with: `. ~/.zshrc`

**Part 4**, setting up new user's home directories.

We need to to place whatever files we want the new users to have in the `/etc/skel` directory, because this is what the system copies when it is creating new user's home directory. See [this sys admin guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/adduser.html) for details.

Copy your user's files (you may need to sudo):

```
cp -r .oh-my-zsh /etc/skel/
cp .zshrc /etc/skel
```

> Now you will be able to add new users and they will have oh-my-zsh by
>   default with whatever custom theme you want them to have.

If you want to change all other existing user's shell to zsh, I would recommend reading [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/373056/set-default-shell-for-existing-user-with-puppet).

Comment: This is the exact same technique I've used on Linux and BSD machines to get ZSH setup and available for all future users. Existing users require a little bit of more work but you get the idea! Wonderful response!

Comment: This answer does not help and is totally missing the point, so minus one.

Answer (score 31):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the marked answer from Caleb is just the *normal per-user installation* steps with adding a .zshrc file to the skel dir and changing the default new-user shell, **but it doesn't actually work or really answer the question** because each user *still* requires the oh-my-zsh dir/would *still require each user to clone the oh-my-zsh dir into their own folder meaning it's not really installed system wide*, it just automatically gives them a zshrc file and changes the default shell to zsh, but without oh-my-zsh in each user folder it will error out.

From what I understand of the question it's asking how to install oh-my-zsh **system-wide** aka have it installed in ONE place and not require manually messing around on each new user/having a git clone of oh-my-zsh on each user dir. Assuming that's the case, here's what I did based off Arch Linux's AUR Package I normally use but was looking for the same on a centos server, however this can be done on any distro. **Credit goes to MarcinWieczorek and the other maintainers**, I just adapted the below so can do the same on non-arch distros.

**If you already have oh-my-zsh installed on root just skip to Step 3. This isn't distro specific just uses the AUR Patch File for zshrc**

---

**Step #1**

Install zsh of course

---

**Step #2**

Install oh-my-zsh as root as normal (shows wget method, see Calebs answer for alternative)

```
sh -c "$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"
```

---

**Step #3**

Move the install to /usr/share so is system-wide

```
#Copy zsh files to /usr/share for all uer access 
mv /root/.oh-my-zsh /usr/share/oh-my-zsh
# Move into the dir and copy the zshrc template to zshrc (which will be the default for users)
cd /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/
cp templates/zshrc.zsh-template zshrc
# Nab the patch file from MarcinWieczorek's AUR Package and apply to the zshrc file
wget https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/plain/0001-zshrc.patch\?h\=oh-my-zsh-git -O zshrc.patch && patch -p1 < zshrc.patch
```

Now oh-my-zsh is installed globally and the user just needs that zshrc file. so NOW is where Caleb's answer comes in though just do the below as /etc/adduser.conf is only on debian whereas the below should be distro independent.

---

**Step #4**

Set it up to be the default on new users

```
# Create hard link to the zshrc file so it creates an actual independent copy on new users
sudo ln /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc /etc/skel/.zshrc
# Set default shell to zsh
sudo adduser -D -s /bin/zsh
```

---

Now that's a **true** installation of oh-my-zsh with all new users automatically having it applied with the /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc settings and no other steps needed.

**Misc Notes**

- **For any pre-existing users with oh-my-zsh:**

  ```
  cp /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc ~/.zshrc
  ```
- You can set **new user OMZ defaults** in /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc
- **Auto Updates are disabled** since new users do not have permissions to update the /usr/share/oh-my-zsh files

  - **To update oh-my-zsh** just cd to /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/ and run 'sudo git pull'
- The oh-my-zsh cache will be handled per-user within each user dir under ~/.oh-my-zsh-cache/ (automatically created)

Comment: `cp templates/zshrc.zsh-templan't answer the question/just looks to be the standard installation which must be performed per-user. Ite zshrc`

This does not look right to me. It looks like you copy-pasted something over the copy command.

Comment: What does the "_Nab the patch file from [..]_" command actually do, and is it needed? I'm getting the following error when I run that: https://pastebin.com/fL54kTxZ

Comment: @Ronaldt, The patch file works and shows what it does linewise. Probably the most important change is the new "home" path of omz at the beginning of zshrc ("zsh=..").

Comment: `adduser -D -s /bin/zsh` failed on Ubuntu 18.04 because bad options. I suppose the implementation is different there and editing `/etc/adduser.conf` is the intended way to go.

Comment: The AUR patch adds a mkdir command for generating zsh's cache folder:
```shell
ZSH_CACHE_DIR=$HOME/.cache/oh-my-zsh
if [[ ! -d $ZSH_CACHE_DIR ]]; then
  mkdir $ZSH_CACHE_DIR
fi
```
that fails on a system without a pre-existing `.cache` folder, like my Ubuntu Docker image. Consider using `mkdir -p` instead.

Comment: +1 clear explanation and it works, but how would one go about installing PowerLevel10k and plugins, namely the ones from YourAboutMeIsBlank's answer.  I've tried to follow that part of his answer, since the zshrc is in the same place, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 10):

If you want a system-wide install of Oh-My-Zsh, a convenient approach that overwrites the least number files is:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git /etc/oh-my-zsh
sudo cp /etc/oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template /etc/skel/.zshrc
sudo mkdir -p /etc/skel/.oh-my-zsh/cache
```

Edit `/etc/skel/.zshrc`:

- Edit the line `export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh` (currently line 5)
- Change the line to be:

```
      export ZSH=/etc/oh-my-zsh
      export ZSH_CACHE_DIR=~/.oh-my-zsh/cache
```

Then edit `/etc/default/useradd` and change the line `SHELL=...` to `SHELL=/bin/zsh`.

That's basically all (of course, git and zsh must be installed already).

To update a pre-existing user: login as them and `cp /etc/skel/.zshrc ~/.zshrc`

**Update:** Please do not edit this. I just rolled back an edit which completely botched it up!

Answer (score 3):

***Login as ROOT***

**Step 1: Install ZSH**

```
# Download and extract ZSH

wget https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/archive/zsh-5.8.tar.gz -P /tmp/demo/zsh
cd /tmp/demo/zsh
tar -xvzf zsh-*
cd zsh-zsh-5.8

# configure and make

sudo ./Util/preconfig
sudo ./configure
sudo make && sudo make install


# Add ZSH to the list of shells

echo /usr/local/bin/zsh | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
```

**Step 2: Install oh-my-zsh**

```
# If you're running the Oh My Zsh install script as part of an automated install, 
# you can pass the flag --unattended to the install.sh script.
# This will have the effect of not trying to change the default shell, and also won't
# run zsh when the installation has finished.

sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)" "" --unattended

# Add oh-my-zsh to /usr/share
mv /root/.oh-my-zsh /usr/share
mv /usr/share/.oh-my-zsh /usr/share/oh-my-zsh
mv /root/.zshrc /usr/share/oh-my-zsh
mv /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/.zshrc /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc

# Modify zshrc to point to /usr/share/oh-my-zsh

sed -i 's|export ZSH="'"$HOME"'/.oh-my-zsh"|export ZSH="\/usr\/share\/oh-my-zsh"|g' /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc
```

***Step 3: Add Extra (Optional - Look at the bottom for extra features)***

***Step 4: Create Symbolic link***

```
# Create Symbolic Links to /etc/skel
sudo ln /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc /etc/skel/.zshrc
```

**Step 5: Add oh-my-zsh for root**

```
# Change shell to ZSH for root
echo "$USER" | chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh
```

**Step 6: Add oh-my-zsh for user**

```
# Change user
su - username

# Copy zshrc to $HOME for user
cp /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc ~/.zshrc

# Change shell to ZSH for user  
echo "$USER" | chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh
```

OR

```
sudo -i -u username bash << EOF
cp /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc ~/.zshrc
echo username | chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh
EOF
```

**EXTRA:**

Change theme to powerlevel10k

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-/usr/share/oh-my-zsh/custom}/themes/powerlevel10k

sed -i 's/ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"/ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k\/powerlevel10k"/g' /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc
```

Enable Auto correction

```
sed -i 's/# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"/ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"/g' /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc
```

Enable Auto suggestions and Syntax highlighting

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-/usr/share/oh-my-zsh/custom}/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions

git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.git ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-/usr/share/oh-my-zsh/custom}/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting

sed -i 's/plugins=(git)/plugins=(\n  git\n  zsh-autosuggestions\n  zsh-syntax-highlighting\n)/' /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc

sed -i 's/plugins=(git)/plugins=(git)\nZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX=true/' /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc
```

Add nord dircolors

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/arcticicestudio/nord-dircolors.git /tmp/demo/dircolors

mv /tmp/demo/dircolors/src/dir_colors /usr/share/
cd /usr/share/
mv /usr/share/dir_colors /usr/share/.dir_colors

tee -a /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc >/dev/null <<'EOF'
test -r "/usr/share/.dir_colors" && eval $(dircolors /usr/share/.dir_colors)
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined **cFINNY**'s answer, reading and understanding the oh-my-zsh install script, the AUR patch in his answer, and fixing the broken `adduser` command to do this install in a `FROM ubuntu:bionic` (Ubuntu 18.04) Dockerfile :

```
RUN git clone \
        -c core.eol=lf \
        -c core.autocrlf=false \
        -c fsck.zeroPaddedFilemode=ignore \
        -c fetch.fsck.zeroPaddedFilemode=ignore \
        -c receive.fsck.zeroPaddedFilemode=ignore \
        --depth=1 \
        --branch master \
        https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh.git \
        /usr/share/oh-my-zsh \
    # Adapt zshrc template
    && cd /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/ \
    && cp templates/zshrc.zsh-template zshrc \
    && sed -i 's/export ZSH=$HOME\/.oh-my-zsh/export ZSH=\/usr\/share\/oh-my-zsh/g' zshrc \
    && sed -i 's/# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"/DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"/g' zshrc \
    && sed -i 's/source $ZSH\/oh-my-zsh.sh//g' zshrc \
    && sed -i 's/ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"/ZSH_THEME="bira"/g' zshrc \
    && echo '\n \
\n \
ZSH_CACHE_DIR=$HOME/.cache/oh-my-zsh \n \
if [[ ! -d $ZSH_CACHE_DIR ]]; then \n \
  mkdir -p $ZSH_CACHE_DIR \n \
fi \n \
 \n \
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh \n \
' >> zshrc \
    # Copy zshrc template to $HOME on user creation
    && ln /usr/share/oh-my-zsh/zshrc /etc/skel/.zshrc \
    # Setting the default shell for new users has no effect since:
  # 1. The default shell is specified when creating new users in entrypoint
  # 2. The `ade enter` command will execute `bash` anyways
    && sed -i 's/DSHELL=\/bin\/bash/DSHELL=\/bin\/zsh/g' /etc/adduser.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also a simple way to do this as well:
Login as the root user and install zsh

- `sudo su`
- `apt-get install zsh`

Then login as another user of the system:

- `su username`
- `export ZSH=/home/username/.oh-my-zsh`
- `sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`

Follow same procedures for all users who want `oh-my-zsh`